# Saving data in RDLC File

Tags: reportviewer, rdlc, syncfusion, dynamic-rdlc-generation

Can any one tell me if it is possible to save data inside an RDLC file, I am using the syncfusion Report Viewer and I want to be able to save the report it generates as a PDF, Execl ect but the problem we have is that we compute the values for the report, they are NOT COMMING FROM A DATABASE, so we tie them to a dataset and then generate the report, the problem I have found is that if I use the WFC service from Syncfusion to save the report and have to switch it back to remote then the data's not render.

Is there a free or payed for component out there that can take the RDLC file, DATA render the report then output a report that I can read in to the report viewer (output prefred RDLC with Data embed), looking at the example syncfusuion provide they have done this.

Answer (score 1):

RDLC does't support to store data inside ReportDefinition.

**FOR EXPORT**

Due to some limintation platform itself can’t export report directly in Syncfusion ReportViewer  in Silverlight , but through the WCF service can export the report .. Please find our online documentation section “How to export RDLC report in Silverlight “ 
Location [here](http://help.syncfusion.com/ug/silverlight/report%20viewer/default.htm#!documents/caniexportanrdlcfile.htm)

This sample demonstrate export functionality inSyncfusion ReportViewer. Please find the sample from following [location](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/113387/RDLCExportApplication-1558437718-1810239165.zip)